# How to send an email through a feedback form using MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a MVC Razor web application which has a feedback form and a database backend.

WEhen I complete the feedback form and click on submit, the information goes into the database.

My question is how do I email this information to an email address, code below:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Feedback(FeedbackModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (this.db.InsertFeedback(model))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("FeedbackSuccessful");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error! We were unable to process your feedback at this time. Please try again later.");
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this and add required references.  (using System.Web.Helpers;)  

[HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Feedback(FeedbackModel model)
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    if (this.db.InsertFeedback(model))
    {
     WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
    WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
    WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
    WebMail.UserName = "youremailID@gmail.com";
    WebMail.Password = "yourpassword";
    WebMail.From = "from@gmail.com";
    WebMail.Send("Email Address", "Mail Subject", "Mail Body");
return RedirectToAction("FeedbackSuccessful");
    }
    else
    {
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error! We were unable to process your feedback at this time. Please try again later.");
    }
    }
    return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, what if the person sending the feedback not have a gmail account?

Comment: Provide smtp details of the domain from which you want to send mail. I have given gmail as an example